# List of count of tag members?

Tags: reports, tags

Is it a report or anything like that, that could display a list of all tags together with a count of contacts with each tag?

Comment: what cms? took a quick look at d7 - views (with civicrm entity) gives me the count of tags - but without the tag name!

Comment: CMS is Drupal 7

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 2):

Not a report, but FYI the "Manage Tags" screen actually shows the usage count for each tag when you click on it:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but I was looking for something that you by one look could get the overview of contacts with tag

Answer (score 1):

In D7 this can be done use CiviCRM Entity and Views and Views Field Views

CiviCRM Entity can give us a View with the data from civicrm_entity_tag

but, there is no 'Relationship' that I can spot to the civicrm_tag table to get the name of the tag, hence you get a table with the Tag ID and the Count. Not so useful.

With views_field_view you can make another view based civicrm_tag to get the tag name, use the Contextual Filter of the tag id

then pull that View in to the first one and apply the same Contextual Filter and bingo you have your table of Tags with a count of entities using it.

PM me and I will zip you the views if you don't want to start from scratch.